# HornetQ concurrent session usage warning

Tags: hornetq

With regards to [this](https://community.jboss.org/message/833996) post, I am using HornetQ 2.4.0 embedded, and using the hornetq core api. I use it to queue messages received via a web service call. I have another thread that dequeues messages synchronously, and processes them. When enqueuing, I sometimes get the "WARN: HQ212051: Invalid concurrent session usage" warning. Does this apply to this embedded usage that I am doing, where I am not using the JMS api? I'm running in embedded jetty, and don't have a container. If I do need to guarantee single thread access, I would have to do my own pool or do a thread local session, correct? (would rather not synch access to the shared objects for performance reasons)